# Can't seem to make Isolation READ COMMITTED work

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate and Spring to control the transactions.

I currently have a Object *Foo* that I want to read from database before I update it. Something like that

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public void update(Foo beingUpdated) {
   Foo beforeUpdate = fooDao.read(beingUpdated.getId());

   checkDifferences(beingUpdated, beforeUpdate);
   fooDao.update(beingUpdated);
}
```

but my problem is that when I read *Foo*, the returned object is the one being updated, not the commited. Am I misunderstanding the use of Isolation? How can I read the object committed at database, not the one being updated?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: that depends on the RDBMS you are using - different RDBMS react differently to the same isolation setting... another point: as long as long you are reading and updating inside the same session/connection you always get the current value even if it is not committed yet...

Comment: I am currently using Oracle. Is there a way that I can obtain the object commited at database, even at the same session? I need to check these differences, because I need to feed it to another service.

Comment: if at all possible then with some combination of trigger and possibly AQ, perhaps together with some Stored Procedure...

Comment: This seems a little overkill for what I am trying to achieve. I just want the object detached from session, so I can read it before the changes.

Comment: Sorry - can't help your there, I know Oracle but don't use hibernate... hope someone else has the answer you are seeking... perhaps this link http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-detached helps.

Comment: Thanks anyway. The first comment already gave me an idea :P If it works, I will post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some options for you:

1. Re-read the entity in another session, perhaps using a method annotated with `@Transactional(propgation=REQUIRES_NEW)` which will give you a new session for that method. This adds DB overhead though: you will need to re-load the entity.
2. Delve into the Hibernate internals using something like [PostUpdateEvent.getOldState()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/event/PostUpdateEvent.html#getOldState%28%29).
3. Save off the state you're interested in with a [LoadEventListener](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/event/LoadEventListener.html). If you put the information into transient fields you can access it later.

None of these options are very palatable, but I have used 1 and 3 successfully in a few places.